# How does a StringBuilder reduce time a Java program takes drastically?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Have two Java code snippets. Sharing them below -

1.

```
Collections.sort(al);
                Iterator<Integer> it = al.iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()){
                        sb.append(it.next());
                        sb.append("\n");
                }
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

2.

```
Collections.sort(al);
                Iterator<Integer> it = al.iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()){
                        System.out.println(it.next());
                }
```

Sharing the time the above programs took -
1. 1.43 seconds
2. 4.28 seconds

I wonder what magic StringBuilder does, can somebody guide?

Comment: Within your loop - Second one involves I/O while first one doesn't

Comment: thanks, sometimes soln is right under your nose and you look everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your StringBuilder but your System.out.println() statements which is slowing down the execution time.

It is slow because

> Bytes had to be sent to the console application -> Each char has to be
>   rendered using a true type font (cause for slow processing) ->
>   Displayed area may have to be scrolled to append a new line to the
>   visible area.

Comment: where you quote is taken from?

Comment: It's from one of the questions on SO

Comment: usually you should add a link to where the quote made, and if it's a duplicate of previous question mark question as duplicate

Comment: For previous questions I used to do the same but someone advised me not to if question is put in another way we should answer as per. That's why only quoted necessary part from other to explain this. Is it wrong?

Comment: When someone read your answer he sees a quote but there's no reference to where the quote is taken from, so quoting seems irrelevant